# Error when I want to install something via pip: "Therefore support for pip in cryptography is deprecated"

Tags: apt, package-management, python, youtube-dl

When I want to install youtube-dl `python3 -m pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` I get this error message:

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography (40.0) will be the last to support Python 3.6. from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied: youtube-dl in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2021.12.17)`

**Questions**

1. what does this mean?
2. what does the last paragraph mean: `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Condition already met: youtube-dl in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2021.12.17)`

Comment: It maybe time to upgrade; Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches EOSS in April 2023 so you're nearing the *end of the road* for major support for that OS.

Answer (score 1):

this error message you received is just a warning that indicates to you that your version of pyhon is no longer supported and not supported by the Pyhthon core team, and that the next of "cryptography" will be the last to support python 3.6, overall it will not affect the installation of youtube-dl dont worry

Then the last paragraph of the output simply indicated that youtube-dl installation was successful, what the message mean is that the installation was done in your user local repository rather the system directory because it didnt have the rights to write in it, again it is a normal message